# Why are most people on the top of the Diablo 2 ladder Paladin?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've been looking at the expansion ladder and you could see one non-paladin every like 8~10 paladins!

What's the deal with Paladins? Are they somehow superior in Diablo 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason Paladins dominate the top of ladders is because of the extremely popular Hammerdin build (attacking with Magic Hammers).

With this build, it is very hard to be killed due to the lack of immunities against magic damage in the game (very few monsters are immune), the concentration aura which has a high % of making a hit not interrupt you, as well as the high resistance that comes with the Paladin items typically in this build (Shako, Spirit or HoZ, Hoto, etc.).

Compound this with achieving the highest FCR breakpoint, an Enigma (to teleport), max block (via Holy Shield & Stats), and a mercenary with Holy Freeze, and you have a very good PVM (and to a lesser extent PVP) character.

Since it's essentially the #1 PVM build, people like to use Hammerdins to bot their way to 99, as he is a good candidate for mass Chaos runs as well as Baal runs (although for Baal runs, the Hammerdin must rely on either their mercenary to kill the second Wave or must invest a few points into Holy Bolt as that wave is magic immune).

Comment: Wut? The second wave is undead and hammers ignore resistances of undead and demons. There is only a handful of creatures in game immune to hammers and the Baal's second wave guys do not belong them. At least it was so a few patches ago. Also, contrary to what you've said, I think concentration is purely offensive spell.

Comment: @Rotsor the latest patch, 1.14 I believe, has changed the casters to be magic immune. Also, Concentration aura, while being an offensive aura, adds an "uninterruption" chance...

Comment: Kotsu, oh, you are right. Blessed Hammer No longer ignores resistances of undead and demons since 1.13. 1.14 is not out yet though. And on uninterruption, it does not make hits miss you, does it?

Comment: @Rotsor No, let me edit that.